# Why number is an invalid data type

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a simple table in toad for Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE medcine
(
    id                 NUMBER,
    name               VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    price              NUMBER,
    supplier_id        NUMBER            NOT NULL,
    company_id         NUMBER            NOT NULL,
    pre_date           DATE              DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL,
    Exp_date           DATE              DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL,
    sell-price         NUMBER,
    effective_material VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)
);
```

but when I run it I get this error:

> Error at line 3
>   ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo:

```
sell-price
```

should be

```
sell_price
```

It is the `-` that is being rejected, because the parser expects a datatype at that position.

By the way, some reformatting must have changed the line numbering, as SQL*Plus for example reports the exact position of the error:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE medcine
  2  (
  3      id                 NUMBER,
  4      name               VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  5      price              NUMBER,
  6      supplier_id        NUMBER            NOT NULL,
  7      company_id         NUMBER            NOT NULL,
  8      pre_date           DATE              DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL,
  9      Exp_date           DATE              DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL,
 10      sell-price         NUMBER,
 11      effective_material VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)
 12  );
    sell-price         NUMBER,
        *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

PL/SQL Developer and SQL Developer both highlight the hyphen character when reporting the error; PL/SQL Developer also places the cursor on it. I expect Toad does something similar.

Also, possibly the table should be named *medicine*.

Comment: Nice going Mr. Robertson. I looked right at it and didn't see that.